# Customize Codeiniter Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, customization, codeigniter-pagination

I am using **codeigniter** pagination but it is return record of tables from database and show pages link, i want to use pagination for my pages view not table.

Comment: Pagination is used to change data in one view not use to change view.

Comment: Update you question with your code.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here(Be clear) ? If you just want pagination in view, just use some bootstrap jquery tables. It will create pagination for you in view.  For pagination in query, use codeingiter pagination library. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html .

Comment: i want to set the link of pagination pages [1] [2] [3]... when i click to page 2 its go which page that i sated and as three diff

Comment: As do table upper the pagination.
Rather than build a table, View to make your information you like showing.

Answer (score 0):

Use these options in pagination with your own custom css classes

```
   $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';

    $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_link'] = 'Next &rarr;';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['prev_link'] = '&larr; Previous';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```